Use Table Valued Parameter in Merge sql statement
I am trying to use sql server's MERGE command. However, I am not sure, how do we pass it as a parameter using Java.
I am setting up SqlParamSource as
private SqlParameterSource getSqlParamsForPollingLogUpdateWithMerge(int[] ids){
        final MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        try{
            SQLServerDataTable table = new SQLServerDataTable();
            table.addColumnMetadata("id",java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            table.setTvpName("dbo.idtable");
            for (int id : ids) {
                table.addRow(id);
            }

            params.addValue("idtable", table);
            return params;
        }catch (Exception ex){
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

    }


My sql looks like:
String sql= "create type dbo.idtable AS TABLE (id INT);" +
                        "MERGE INTO table1 AS tgt" +
                "USING :idtable as src\n" +
                "ON tgt.id=src.id" +
                "WHEN MATCHED THEN" +
                "UPDATE SET ...<fewupdates here>" +
                "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN" +
                "INSERT <inserts here>;";

The problem that I am facing is the data type 'dbo.idtable' is not getting resolved. I am unsure how to proceed now.

I'm not sure it works like this. You have to create the type ahead of time once. Also, a bit unsure you can bind a merge source as parameter like that.

Considering the problem you're asking about is how to bind the TVF from Java, tagging [[tag:java]] seems important here.

You certainly will need the type to be created before trying to submit a batch with a parameter of that type. I rarely have anything to do with Java so can't comment on the rest of it

If you can't or don't want to create the table type ahead of time, you can pass a JSON string and use OPENJSON to parse it in TSQL.  Or you can't or don't want to figure out how to use TVPs in JDBC. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-ver16

OPENJSON() is faster and scales much better than TVPs.   Superior in just about every way.

The posted query also exhibits a lack of whitespace between tokens. i.e.: MERGE INTO table1 AS tgtUSING :idtable as src... isn't going to work all that well.

Using OpenJson worked for me. This is how sql looks like now.
:json is the json array having multiple json records with one id key.
 "MERGE INTO table1 AS tgt \n" +
                "USING openjson(:json) with (id int '$.id') as src \n" +
                "ON tgt.id=src.id " +
                "WHEN MATCHED THEN " +
                "UPDATE SET <> " +
                "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN " +
                "INSERT <>;"

